# XAMPP MySQL Shutdown Unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp

Tried to run MySQL in XAMPP and it won't start, got this in the error log:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-07-09 16:43:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-07-09 16:43:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-07-09 16:43:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-07-09 16:43:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-07-09 16:43:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-07-09 16:43:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk > size = 16M
2020-07-09 16:43:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-07-09 16:43:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-07-09 16:43:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-07-09 16:43:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. 
Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-07-09 16:43:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-07-09 16:43:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-07-09 16:43:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log sequence number 192714408; transaction id 58253
2020-07-09 16:43:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-07-09 16:43:26 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-07-09 16:43:26 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

This is what shows up in XAMPP command log:

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums
```

Please help

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50003447/mariadb-not-starting-plugin-feedback-is-disabled.

Comment: Refer this too: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191656/xampp-mysql-troubleshooting-with-mysql-server.

Comment: Please make sure that you don't have multiple instances of mysql running.